# Replace NUL in a text file from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, aix

Need to replace NUL occurance from a text file via shell script. In windows notepad++ replaced it with \x00 regular expression. Not sure how to get this done at aix/linux shell scripts. File will be received from another server via sftp and we need to remove the NUL before processing it via PLSQL[image]

Comment: `tr -d '\0'`? Or `sed 's/\x0//g'` if you want to use `sed`’s `-i` option?

Comment: On AIX, the default `sed` program does this automagically: `/usr/bin/sed '' zerotest.dat >zeroless.dat`

Comment: THank you very much.. It worked like a charm.